# CSS selector where "inside" & "preceded by" both apply

Tags: html, css

Question to CSS experts. A HTML page is generated on the BackEnd-server side and arrives to me on the FrontEnd-client with a structure like:

```
<div class="AA">  <!-- (1) -->
    ...
  <span class="SS"> ssss </span>
</div>
<div>     <!-- (2) -->
  <span> xxx </span>
```

Is there any way to CSS-select `<span>` xxx ? (where the sequence in the file is thus):

- `<span>` xxx is inside a `<div>`  (2)
- `<div>` (2) follows a previous `div.AA` (1)
- `div.AA` contains a 'span.SS'

Said otherwise, once selected `div.AA span.SS` how I can add the further relationship `div.AA + (div span)` ?
If possible I'd like to select that span only with a CSS syntax (better if CSS version 2) without asking to add/change the HTML I'm receiving.

Comment: You can't. There is no CSS selector yet that allows backtracking. In the future, you will have to do something like this `div:has(span.SS) + div span`. Here's the documentation on [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

Comment: you want to select a span which is a child of a div which is an adj to a div with AA class ? 

`div.AA + div span `

Comment: With Pure CSS, You can only use `div.AA + div > span { ... }` You cannot test where `div.AA` has `span.SS` or not. For this you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very very much to all ! Especially to @BramVanroy for the `:has` info and to @muhammad-usman for proposing the JavaScript workaround, and to all the others that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the logic of what you are trying to achieve and see if there is a simpler way.

That notwithstanding the closest you could get is the following but this will pick up any child element

```
.AA:not(:empty) + div span {color: #ccc;}
```

Comment: Not just elements, also text nodes.

Comment: That is true. It always bugs me that.